# The type or namespace name could not be found, but it's in the project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Error in source:

```
Regel 27:     using System.Web.Routing;
Regel 28:     using alina1617;
Regel 29:     using aline1617.Models.AccountModel;
Regel 30:     
Regel 31:
```

> Foutbericht van compiler: CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'aline1617' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

I only have on project (alina1617) and that's the project I'm working in.

Trying to run this view:

```
@model alina1617.Models.FaculteitModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GebruikersList";
}

<h2>GebruikersList</h2>

<div>
    <h4>FaculteitModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Naam)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Naam)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

So for some reason I'm getting this error? I created a controller and created a view from that controller, so the view was just generated by VS, so it should be working fine?

Comment: Is it `alina1617` or `aline1617`?

Comment: Alina. But I've never written aline. (Working on project with multiple people).

Comment: Yes, you have: "Regel 29:     using aline1617.Models.AccountModel;"

Comment: just a spelling mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo:

```
 Regel 29:     using aline1617.Models.AccountModel;
```

should be

```
 Regel 29:     using alina1617.Models.AccountModel;
```

`alina` instead of `aline`.

Comment: Usually we vote to close typo-questions instead of answering them.

Comment: Was a typo in web config... Thanks, I feel silly.